# Please burninate the [server] tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, serverfault

On Server Fault, we have the [server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/server) tag with 2283 questions as of this post. The general consensus is that it's a useless tag and it doesn't help to sort questions, but the sheer number of questions tagged with it makes manual removal of the tag impractical and very undesirable.

Any time I see that tag used on the front page I make no apologies for removing it, but this will never get all of the tagged questions, so we need a better solution.

Can you please burninate this tag, and then we can slowly (so as not to flood the front page) retag the questions which are left as untagged. Could you also please prevent this tag from ever being used again.

Comment: I'm in, and I agree, it needs dev intervention to kill this one with fire rather than us^h^h you editing the bejesus out of it.

Comment: I came back. I added a tag-wiki to it saying in effect "this is a useless tag" and changed it. Constant vigilance will be needed to prevent its recurrence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

Watch out for the [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions though.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jeff. You have no idea how long that tag has been annoying the hell out of me :-)

Comment: amazing service... Is now a bad time to ask about the [tag:error] tag too? http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/error

Comment: @robert sure, error is gone too

Comment: Wow... thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry Jeff, also just noticed we've got a plural [servers] as well. Can you burninate that too?

Comment: @JefAtwood: Please Burninate [slowness]

Comment: @JefAtwood: I just found 2 questions from today (1 hour and 5 hours ago)  that had the server tag ? I thought it had been BURNINATED

Comment: @Iain, I think you have to specifically ask for blackholing as Jeff probably doesn't fully comprehend the magnitude of our burnination desires.

Comment: @ChrisS: cheers @JefAtwood: please blackhole tags: server, servers, slowness.

Comment: @iain I added `^servers?$` to the intrinsic tags for serverfault -- this will block them